# Uncaught (in promise) on ajax call NodeJS app with Python script on AWS

Tags: node.js, ajax, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, promise

I have an NodeJS/Express app that works fine on localhost. When I try to ran it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk i get an error :
[image]

I narrowed it down the router function that calls python script. The code is below:

```
router.get ('/new_bids',async (req, res) => {
   let options = {
   mode: 'text',
   scriptPath: 'public/pythonscripts/',
};
  await PythonShell.run('new_bids_alert.py', options, function (err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;
  num_of_bids = results[0]
  res.json({success : true, new_bids: parseInt(num_of_bids)})
  });
})
```

I assume something is missing on the settings for AWS environment but can't figure it out. I appreciate any guidance that can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that there is a `502 bad gateway` in the `new_bids_alert.py`, but, syntactically the code has problems as well, You are `await`ing a function that is not returning a promise. So, you need to promisify it and `await` it.

```
const { promisify } = require('util')

router.get('/new_bids', async (req, res) => {
  let options = {
    mode: 'text',
    scriptPath: 'public/pythonscripts/',
  };
  const promiseRun = promisify(PythonShell.run);
  let num_of_bids = 0;
  const resp = {
    success: true,
    new_bids: 0
  }
  try{
    const results = await promiseRun('new_bids_alert.py', options);
    resp.new_bids = parseInt(results[0]);
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
    resp.success = false;
  }
  res.json(resp);
});
```

**Note**: This will not solve whatever is the problem with the python script. I would suggest you to post the python question separately with `python` tag.

Comment: Aritra Chakraborty. Thank You for fixing the code. You are correct I didn't solve the problem. As far python script goes, it works fine on localhost, hence I believe the issue is probably with settings on AWS.